# Networkx node without edges has degree

Tags: python, networkx

I created a (directed) graph with networkx on python and I wanted to sort all my nodes by their weighted degree.

But I found a node that has no connexions but still has a positive degree... which should not be possible.

Here is an exemple to highlight the problem.

```
n = 1202915887759679488  # ID of a problematic node

list_edges = G.edges(nbunch=n)
deg = G.degree(n)
weighted_deg = G.degree(n, weight='weight')

print("list of edges connected to n :", list_edges)
print("degree of n :", deg)
print("weighted degree of n :", weighted_deg)
```

```
list of edges connected to n : []
degree of n : 19
weighted degree of n : 14.994423627853394
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example so that we can reproduce the error also on our pc?

Comment: Ok I wanted to create a little example but I found my mistake doing it.

In directed graph, G.edges() return only out_edges from specified nodes. And this node has only in_edges.

Comment: This is often what happens to me when creating a minimal example, which is why it's actually a useful debugging tool.